# Split error to retrieve integer in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string date = dr["event_date"].ToString();
string[] eventdate = date.Split('-');
int date_no = Convert.ToInt32(eventdate[2]);
```

I get an error

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

on the last line

Comment: and what is the error saying?

Comment: Perhaps you should validate your assumptions about the output of `ToString()`. Do you know how to use the debugger?

Comment: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
0
down vote

Line 94: int date_no = Convert.ToInt32(eventdate[2]);

I got an error "Index was outside the bounds of the array" in the above line

Comment: Try `int date_no = DateTime.Parse(date).Day;`

Comment: Can you post the value of `date` ?

Comment: The error clearly say's that there is not a single element at the used index `2`

Comment: @Jawad pls post the `date` variable value or in which format you try to retrieve the value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Answer (score -1):

```
int date_no = Convert.ToInt32(eventdate[1])
```

Array index starts from 0

Comment: Not the one who down-voted you, but people tend to down-vote "lazy" answers. Your answer would be more beneficial to explain the indexing error, why it happened, etc. so that OP actually learns something from it, not just copy-paste your code without even understanding what went wrong in the first place, which clearly they don't, hence the post.